# glfwSetCursorPosCallback to function in another class

Tags: c++, callback, glfw

I'm really stuck:

I have the mainWindow and in the main game loop I do:

```
// poll for input
glfwPollEvents();

this->controls->handleInput(window, world->getPlayer());
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, controls->handleMouse);
```

What I want to do is to have one class responsible for the controls and to have this class also handle the mouse.

I always get:

```
'Controls::handleMouse': function call missing argument list; use '&Controls::handleMouse' to create a pointer to member
```

Now when I try this I get:

```
'GLFWcursorposfun glfwSetCursorPosCallback(GLFWwindow *,GLFWcursorposfun)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (__thiscall Controls::* )(GLFWwindow *,double,double)' to 'GLFWcursorposfun'
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, as GLFWcursorposfun is just a typedef with a GLFWwindow and two doubles.

As the function is in another class I tried creating a prototype for it, like:

```
class Controls {
    void handleInput(GLFWwindow *window, object *gameObject);
    void handleMouse(GLFWwindow *window, double mouseXPos, double mouseYPos);
};
```

but to no avail.

edit: Of course I can set it to &Controls::handleMouse if I make the function static, but I'd rather be able to create multiple Controls-Objects with different cameras and gameObjects they manipulate.

Also, how to get in the correct camera/gameObject data then?

Comment: you can see my answer to this question, which in short makes uses of `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676971/pointing-to-a-function-that-is-a-class-member-glfw-setkeycallback/28660673#28660673

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a class's member function as a function. `glfwSetCursorPosCallback` it's expecting a function and throwing the error because it gets a member function.

In other words your expected to provide a global function and pass that to `glfwSetCursorPosCallback`.

If you really want the controls object to get the cursor position callback you could store an instance of Controls in a global variable and pass on the callback to that instance. Something like this:

```
static Controls* g_controls;

void mousePosWrapper( double x, double y )
{
    if ( g_controls )
    {
        g_controls->handleMouse( x, y );
    }
}
```

Then when you call `glfwSetCursorPosCallback` you can pass the `mousePosWrapper` function:

```
glfwSetCursorPosCallback( window, mousePosWrapper );
```

Comment: Of course you're right. This is rather unflexible tho, so I refrain from using the callback function and decided it's better to actually and actively grab the cursor-position instead.

Answer (score 3):

My solution: Do not use the callback-setter. Instead I do the following:

```
glfwPollEvents();

this->controls->handleInput(window, mainObj);
this->controls->handleMouse(window, mainObj);
```

And within handleMouse I do:

```
GLdouble xPos, yPos;
glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xPos, &yPos);
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution would be to associate a pointer to `controls` to the `GLFWindow`. See [`glfwSetWindowUserPointer`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651).

The pointer can be retrieved at an time form the `GLFWWindow` object by [`glfwGetWindowUserPointer`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga17807ce0f45ac3f8bb50d6dcc59a4e06). Of course the return type is `void*` and has to be casted to `Controls*`.

Instead of the global function or static method a [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) can be used. e.g:

```cpp
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, this->controls);

glfwSetCursorPosCallback( window, [](GLFWwindow *window, double x, double y)
{
    if (Controls *controls = static_cast<Controls*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window)))
        controls->handleMouse(window, x, y);
} );
```